# Python - CSV File, making sure an answer is on the same line as what is asked

Tags: python, csv

Sorry for the long title.

Basically, my problem is, I have been given this pretty small project to create a Geography Quiz which asks the user what the capital city of a certain country is. The project itself is very easy, I could do it rather quickly, because it suggests you randomise a question from a Countries list, and then check if the users answer equals the same place in the answer list. ( Sorry if you don't get what I mean )

However, I want to take it one step further, I have a data CSV file which has over 150 countries and capitals in it in the format

CountryCapital
So,
FranceParis

What I want my program to do is to ask the user what the capital city of a country is, and the country will be randomised from row[0] in the CSV file. Then when the user goes to answer, say if the question was what is the capital of Australia? If they enter Sydney, I want it to check through the CSV file and see if Australia is on the same line as Sydney in the format AustraliaSydney , but because Sydney won't be on the same line, tell them it's a wrong answer. Then the next question, if it said what's the capital of France, and they enter Paris, it checks to see if Paris and France are together, then it will give the right answer.

This is what I have so far, it's nothing at all really, because I'm kind of new to CSV manipulation, any help is appreciated.

```
import csv
import random
words = dict(csv.reader(open('Data.csv')))
randomWord = random.choice(words.keys())
correctAnswer = words[randomWord]
```

This could well be wrong because as I was searching through the interwebs looking for a pointer in the right direction, this is all I got,
[image: Sample of the Data.csv]

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps a short sample of the .csv contents is in order.

Comment: Added a small sample to the main post.

Comment: Can you explain the format of the data? Why is it like that?

Comment: To be honest erip, I don't know, I downloaded this CSV file off of the internet months ago, and this project just coincidentally came up, so I just thought I might as well make some use of it

Answer (score 2):

```
import csv
import random

countries_capials = dict(csv.reader(open('Data.csv')))

# assuming Data.csv is a comma separated file as so:
# France,Paris
# Australia,Sydney

while True:
    random_country = random.choice(countries_capials.keys())
    answer = countries_capials[random_country]
    print "What's the capial of %s" % random_country
    user_answer = raw_input(">>")
    if user_answer == answer:
        print "That's right!"
    else:
        print "That's wrong!"
```

Output:

```
What's the capial of France
>>Paris
That's right!
What's the capial of Australia
>>New York
That's wrong!
```

You got everything you need in your example, you are only missing the `raw_input()` and `if/else` bit.

## EDIT

Using [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/icyrockcom/country-capitals/master/data/country-list.csv) list of country/capital as data:

```
csv_file = csv.reader(open('country-list.csv'))
countries_capials = {country:capital for (country,capital,capital_type)  in csv_file}
```

We create the dictionary using [dict-comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/).

Comment: And if Data.csv is not a comma separated file, what should I change?

Comment: I think this is a better answer than mine. +1

Comment: I wouldn't need raw input because I use 3.4.2 version of Python

Comment: @Thom9son, well , csv file ARE comma separeted, it's in it's name! But in your case, if you are using FranceParis you would have to work a way to split this in two, It will be a bit of hassle, since some Countries could have two words ex `Czech Republic`, which in your file would show as `CzechRepublicPraga`

Comment: I'll just have a look on the internet for a comma seperated one :p thanks

Comment: Yes, it would be best. It will probably very easy to find. But if you want the challenge, try to come up with a way to separate your file, you might learn a lot with this.

Comment: @f.rodrigues Good point about Czech Republic. This will not work.

Comment: Ok, @f.rodrigues I changed my data.csv file so it actually does have commas, here is a link to it: http://i.imgur.com/dTxvOi5.png yet your program still does not work, and I get this error: ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Comment: It seems that you have one cell with "Country,Capital", it should be two cells one for country and the second for capital. You can fix this by copying all the column and pasting in a empty text file. You will end-up with the desired format.

Comment: Or you can use any form of slicing in your program (is that excel?), to split in two the cell. If that's excel you can do it easily by using: *Data tab, under Tools, click Text to Columns.*  and using the *Convert Text to Columns Wizard*

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/icyrockcom/country-capitals/master/data/country-list.csv
Here's a country-capital list that you can use, you can ignore the third column (delete it if you want).

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your data file is of the following format, where its not comma separated, but each line represents a country and a city joined together with no spaces, but each is capitalized like this:

`FranceParis
UnitedKingdomLondon
etc`

The following should work:

```
import re
import random

lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('countres.csv')]

countries = {}
for pair in lines:
    split = re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', pair)
    city = split[-1]
    country = ''.join(split[:-1])

    countries[country] = city

for i in range(len(countries)):
    curCountry = random.choice(countries.keys())
    print "What's the capital of %s?" % curCountry
    user_answer = raw_input(">>")

    if user_answer == countries[curCountry]:
        print "Correct"
    else:
        print "Incorrect"

    del countries[curCountry]
```

First you need to read in the csv file and split everything up into dictionary keys/values. The rest is trivial from that point as you just randomly choose a key, get input, and check the value associated with that key